# Nomenclature help: action vs. module and “pointed” monadic algebras are module objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, modules, monoidal-categories, universal-algebra

I'm confused about some nomenclature in a paper by J. Goguen from 1975. I'm happy to use definitions however they appear. But I aim to summarise the paper for a non-expert audience and I want them to be able to “Google” modern terminology to find helpful resources. My problem is that I don't know the terminology myself: I'm just a grunt that uses definitions as they are given. I enjoy algebraic taxonomy, but I'm just a tourist.

So any insight you, dear reader, can add would be most appreciated. I'd also like to keep from embarrassing myself to an audience of mathematicians who may read my thesis.

#### TL;DR

Assume herein that $(, ⊗, 1_)$ is a cartesian monoidal category with finite coproducts.

Gougen's main definitions and theorems rest on two isomorphisms:
$$
\textbf{Act}^{X^\ast} ≅ \textbf{Mond}^X \quad\text{and}\quad \textbf{Act}_•^{X^\ast} ≅ \textbf{Mod}^X
$$
where

- $\textbf{Act}^M$ is the category of (right) monoid actions for an internal monoid $M ∈ \textbf{Mon}_$
- $\textbf{Mond}^X$ is the category of “$X$-monadic algebras”, which as far as I can tell, are just plain algebras of the endofunctor $(- ⊗ X) \colon  \rightarrow $. Goguen makes no explicit use of monads, except to invoke their name.
- $\textbf{Act}_•^{M}$ is the category of “pointed” right $M$-actions, which is an $M$-action $S ⊗ M \rightarrow S$ with a global element $1_ \rightarrow S$.
- $\textbf{Mod}^X$, the category of “pointed” $X$-monadic algebras, which he identifies as $X$-modules.
- $(-)^*$ is a functor from $$ to free monoid objects in $\textbf{Mon}_$.

Looking in nLab, a [module object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+object) is exactly what Goguen calls an $M$-action! (Except that nLab describes a left action.) In fact, nLab says that module objects are alternatively called *action objects*.

So I'd like to keep the name $M$-action and the category $\textbf{Act}^M_$, since it is evocative of my intended use. But would like to rename $X$-monadic algebra to $(- ⊗ X)$-algebra (a plain ol' functor algebra) and then a “pointed” $(- ⊗ X)$-algebra is a $1 ⊕ (- ⊗ X)$-algebra.

My concern is that there is some devil in the details. The isomorphisms above are specifically on $X^\ast$, which, of course, can be forgotten back to $$ to form the basis for a list-monad (once the relevant natural transformations are defined).

## Questions

1. Any idea why Goguen uses that definition for a module? In the minds of algebraists, does it invoke some intuition from the algebraic notion of a module that isn't obvious to me?
2. Do my proposed changes in nomenclature make sense? If so, are they an improvement to any audience you could imagine, or am I making too much of things?

The relevant definitions are below.

---

#### Goguen's definitions

- The specific paper is Goguen's (1975) “Discrete-Time Machines in Closed Monoidal Categories. I”
- Also assume the standard definition of internal monoids/monoid objects giving the category $\textbf{Mon}_$
- Free monoids $(M^\ast, ⧺, ι₀)$ are defined in the usual way, with $X^\ast = \bigoplus_{n ∈ ℕ} X^{⊗ n}$ along with concatenation ($⧺$) and unit $ι₀$ as the 0-th coproduct injection---shown to witness a free-forgetful adjunction. (I've modernized the notation a bit.)

Now here is the series of definitions that gives me pause:

1. Given $(M, μ, e) ∈ \textbf{Mon}_$, a **right $M$-action** is a $$-arrow $ \colon S ⊗ M \rightarrow S$ for $S ∈ $ and satisfying two commutative diagrams that amount to an association pentagon and unitor triangle that enforce the preservation of the monoid:
   [image]
   where $α$ is the associator, $ρ$ is the right unitor of $$'s monoidal structure.
   Homomorphisms are $h \colon S \rightarrow S′$ with committing triangles: $α′ ∘ (h ⊗ M) = h ∘ α$, giving the induced category $\textbf{Act}^{M}$.

   - This definition is consonant with modern literature, so I'm satisfied with it.
2. Let $X ∈ $. Then an **$X$-monadic algebra** is a $$-arrow $δ \colon S ⊗ X \rightarrow S$ with homomorphisms $h \colon S \rightarrow S′$ with commuting rectangles: $δ′ ∘ (h ⊗ X) = h ∘ δ$ giving the induced category $\textbf{Mond}^X$.

   - I would package this as a tuple, *drop the monad talk*, and call it an algebra of the endofunctor $(- ⊗ X)$. Then, $\textbf{Mond}^X$ is just $(- ⊗ X)\text{-}\textbf{Alg}$, the category of algebras of the functor.
   - I wonder if he calls it monadic because (even if he doesn't say so) the fact that
     $$\textbf{Act}^{X^\ast} ≅ \textbf{Mond}^X$$ and $(-)^\ast$ induces a monad.
3. A **pointed $M$-action** is a tuple $(S, α, σ)$ where $α$ is an $M$-action and $σ$ is a global element. Homomorphisms of these additionally satisfy a triangle for preserving the base-point.
4. An **$X$-module** is a tuple $(X, S, δ, σ)$ where $δ$ is an $X$-monadic algebra and $σ$ is a global element $(1_, S)$. Homomorphisms of these additionally satisfy a triangle for preserving the base-points. This gives the category $\textbf{Mod}_$.

### NB:

I am aware of fixpoints of functors, and the relationship that will unfold. That's part of what I'm writing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Action versus module**

In modern category theory parlance, *action* and *module* are typically interchangeable, and their use comes down to author preference: this is a historical artefact of the differing nomenclature of *actions* for monoids, and *modules* for rings (categorically, both are instances of the same  phenomenon). Generally speaking, my experience is that you are more likely to encounter *action* in literature motivated by computer science, and *module* in literature motivated by mathematics. However, there does not appear to be any real reason to prefer one over the other. Therefore, your usage of *$M$-action* is completely standard.

In algebra generally, precedence has been given historically to more well structured objects (e.g. groups over monoids), leading to terminology like *semigroup* and *nonunital algebra*. Gougen's terminology choice is inspired by a blend of algebraic nomenclature, using *action* to refer to less structured objects, and *module* to refer to more structured objects. He mentions this choice in the introduction, referring to the modules in the work of Kalman, and contrasting them with *semimodules* (i.e. nonpointed actions).

Personally, I find using both action and module with different meanings potentially confusing given the typical usage in category theory. I would suggest the terminology *pointed $M$-action* instead (which Gougen uses himself, informally). While it's true that these are the same as algebras for the endofunctor $I + ({-}) \otimes X$, I would suggest that *pointed action* is more readable than the mathematical notation.

(As a side note, note that it is generally preferable to use $+$ for the coproduct, rather than $\oplus$, which is often taken to denote an arbitrary monoidal structure, possibly distributing over $\otimes$.)

**Monadic algebras**

For a monoid $M$ in a monoidal category $\mathscr C$, $({-}) \otimes M$ carries the structure of a monad, sometimes called the [action monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+monad). It is the monad associated to the free–forgetful adjunction between the monoidal category and the category of (right) $M$-actions. In other words, the $M$-actions are the algebras for the monad $({-}) \otimes M$.

For an object $X$ in $\mathscr C$, we can also form the category of (right) $X$-actions, which are precisely the algebras for the endofunctor $({-}) \otimes X$. When $\mathscr C$ admits the construction of free monoids $({-})^*$ (i.e. when the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Mon}(\mathscr C) \to \mathscr C$ admits a left adjoint), the forgetful functor from the category of $X$-actions to $\mathscr C$ also admits a left adjoint, and is furthermore [monadic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+functor). The induced monad is given by $({-}) \otimes X^*$. In other words, the $X$-actions are the algebras for the monad $({-}) \otimes X^*$. This kind of monad is known as an [algebraically-free monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+monad), because its algebras are algebras for an endofunctor.

Presumably this monadicity result is why Gougen uses the terminology *$X$-monadic algebra*. However, the terminology is not standard, and I personally do not find it evocative. Your proposal of $({-} \otimes X)$-algebra is completely sensible. Alternatively, you could simply use *$X$-action*: in this case one relies on context to disambiguate between the actions for an object and the actions for a monoid. However, this is the same as when one variably talks about the algebras for an endofunctor and the algebras for a monad.